# Why was my answer removed with no explanation?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

At least provide some explanation when removing people's posts, Stack Overflow!

[image]

Comment: Since it doesn't link for you, then it's probably the entire question getting deleted. When a question gets deleted, all the answers go with it.

Comment: Hey, I lost 12 rep today because apparently 6 posts I'd edited all got deleted at once. It happens, nothing to worry about :)

Comment: @Mystical I thought that a question can't be deleted if there are answers?

Comment: @Oleksiy Yes it can, just not by a unilateral delete from the OP.

Comment: For the 10ks, [here is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257452/loop-over-a-multidimensional-array-not-working-and-instead-getting-only-one-null). It was deleted by a moderator, after being closed on June 23rd. Your answer, however, had received 2 upvotes and 1 downvote, and was deleted *first* by a moderator, presumably in response to a flag.

Comment: A question can be self-deleted if there are *no* answers with a positive score.

Comment: @CodyGray but the removal of the answer took 18 points away, doesn't that mean that it was voted up twice and down once, leaving it with a rating of +1?

Comment: I said that. "Your answer, however, had received 2 upvotes and 1 downvote". I also said that it was deleted *first* by a moderator, making the deletion of the question irrelevant. Then the question was deleted by another moderator. Which was allowed despite there being another undeleted answer with a positive score because moderators are not subject to that rule Kevin's talking about; it applies only to the author of the question.

Comment: @CodyGray: That’s a bug, actually; I didn’t delete it 9 hours ago. I deleted it June 23rd, realized the question was TL, undeleted it and closed the question. Nice catch — wanna report it? :D

Comment: @minitech Hmm, I see that when I look at the revision history. But it still shows you as having deleted it when the question was deleted. Curiously, it *does not* show that for one of the answers. I guess I can report it, but don't you need the Meta rep worse than I do? ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a question gets deleted, all the answers go with it.

This is likely what happened here. Since you have less than 10k and the event doesn't link through, then the only possibility is that it is an answer where the entire question got deleted.
(< 10ks can't see deleted questions. So there's no point in linking it.)